# Calling Java from PLSQL causing oracle.aurora.vm.ReadOnlyObjectException

Tags: java, oracle, exception, plsql

All of a sudden since the 23rd December we are getting an error in our Production when a small Java code is being executed from PLSQL:

```
oracle.aurora.vm.ReadOnlyObjectException
```

From what we can see, nothing has changed - the same code works within our SIT environment.

Has anyone seen this issue before or know what causes and how to fix it?

Calling PLSQL code:

```
status_num := TMJ_HTTP_POST(url_chr
                           ,user_id_chr
                           ,password_chr
                           ,wallet_path_chr
                           ,wallet_pass_chr
                           ,send_msg_clob
                           ,received_clb);
```

PLSQL Wrapper:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TMJ_HTTP_POST(url            IN     VARCHAR2
                                    ,username       IN     VARCHAR2
                                    ,password       IN     VARCHAR2
                                    ,walletPath     IN     VARCHAR2
                                    ,walletPassword IN     VARCHAR2
                                    ,sendMsg        IN     CLOB
                                    ,recvMsg        IN OUT CLOB)
RETURN NUMBER
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
  NAME 'TMJ_HTTP.httpPost(java.lang.String
                         ,java.lang.String
                         ,java.lang.String
                         ,java.lang.String
                         ,java.lang.String
                         ,java.sql.Clob
                         ,java.sql.Clob[])
  return int';
```

Java code:

```
create or replace and compile java source named tmj_http as
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.sql.Clob;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Credentials;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookiePolicy;


/**
 * TMJ_HTTP Client
 * utilising the Apache Commons HTTPClient version 3.1 which runs under JDK 1.4
 * which is available in the Oracle 10g database
 *
 * Assumes a file called truststore.cer with password of truststore resides
 * in the same directory as the wallet file
 */
public class TMJ_HTTP
{
  static int timeout = 30000; // 30 second timeout

  public TMJ_HTTP()
  {
  }

  public static int httpPost(String urlStr, String username, String password, String walletLocation, String walletPassword, Clob sendMsgClob, Clob[] recvMsgClob)
  {
    int responseCode = 0;
    StringBuffer sendMsgBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String sendMsg;
    String[] recvMsg = new String[1];

    try
    {
      // Convert the input Clob to a String
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(sendMsgClob.getCharacterStream());
      String line = null;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        sendMsgBuffer.append(line);
      if (br != null)
        br.close();
      sendMsg = sendMsgBuffer.toString();

      responseCode = httpPost(urlStr, username, password, walletLocation, walletPassword, sendMsg, recvMsg);

      // Convert the returned String to the output Clob
      if (recvMsg != null && recvMsg[0] != null)
        recvMsgClob[0].setString(1, recvMsg[0]);
    }
    catch (java.sql.SQLException e)
    {
      responseCode = 501;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      responseCode = 501;
    }

    return responseCode;
  }


  public static int httpPost(String urlStr, String username, String password, String walletLocation, String walletPassword, String sendMsg, String[] recvMsgArr)
  {
    int responseCode = 0;
    String recvMsg = "";

    /* Uncomment out to allow debugging */
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog");
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime", "true");
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire.header", "debug");
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.headers", "debug");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "SSL");  // Loads of debugging of the SSL connection


    System.getProperties().put("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "HTTPClient");

    // Define the SSL information
    if (walletLocation != null && walletPassword != null)
    {
      String walletPath = "";
      int pos = walletLocation.lastIndexOf('/');
      if (pos == -1)
        pos = walletLocation.lastIndexOf('\\');
      if (pos >= 0)
        walletPath = walletLocation.substring(0, pos + 1);

      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", walletLocation);
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", walletPassword);
      if (walletLocation.endsWith(".p12"))
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");
      else
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", walletPath + "truststore.cer");
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "truststore");
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
    }

    HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
    // httpclient.getParams().setSoTimeout(timeout);
    // httpclient.getParams().setConnectionManagerTimeout(timeout);

    // Define the authentication information
    Credentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
    httpclient.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, defaultcreds);

    PostMethod method = new PostMethod();

    try
    {
      // Set the Cookie Policy
      method.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.RFC_2109);

      // Set the URI to post to
      method.setURI(new URI(urlStr, false));

      // Set the header information
      method.addRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
      method.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0");
      method.addRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");
      method.addRequestHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
      method.addRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

      // Define the data to send
      method.setRequestBody(sendMsg);

      // Execute the request
      responseCode = httpclient.executeMethod(method);

System.out.println("####### Response Code : " + responseCode);
      if (responseCode == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)
      {
        // Still Consume the Response Body
        method.getResponseBodyAsString();
      }
      else
      {
System.out.println("####### Reading response buffer");
        // Read the Reply
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
        String readLine;
        while(((readLine = br.readLine()) != null))
        {
          recvMsg += readLine;
System.out.println("####### line : " + readLine);
        }
      }
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
      recvMsg = getStackTrace(e);
      responseCode = 501;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      recvMsg = getStackTrace(e);
      responseCode = 501;
    }
    finally
    {
      // Clean up the system properties.
      System.getProperties().remove("javax.net.ssl.keyStore");
      System.getProperties().remove("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword");
      System.getProperties().remove("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType");
      System.getProperties().remove("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
      System.getProperties().remove("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword");
      System.getProperties().remove("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType");
      if (method != null)
        method.releaseConnection();
    }

    recvMsgArr[0] = recvMsg;

System.out.println("####### Done - response : " + recvMsg);

    return responseCode;
  }

  public static String getStackTrace(Throwable aThrowable) {
    final Writer result = new StringWriter();
    final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
    aThrowable.printStackTrace(printWriter);
    return result.toString();
  }
}
```

Exception Log:

```
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 38 D8 87 DB 8C E1 07 5B   D3 09 FC 5F 44 46 A5 9B  8......[..._DF..
0010: AC E0 03 96 50 FC 3A 03   68 1B CC 9E D6 38 3B EA  ....P.:.h....8;.
0020: BF 00 6C 67 76 17 DA DA   8B 76 61 D7 36 17 C2 65  ..lgv....va.6..e
0030: 86 44 6D AB CE 3C E9 D2   59 01 EB 16 05 89 07 25  .Dm..<..Y......%
0040: E7 16 32 D2 9F 34 2B E7   94 FE 1F F5 03 E5 3A C8  ..2..4+.......:.
0050: CF 3D 53 29 4E 6F 8D 1F   B1 64 20 E9 9C 8A A2 65  .=S)No...d ....e
0060: C5 40 DA 61 EB 61 D7 11   0E 4C 63 D8 11 97 B0 0D  .@.a.a...Lc.....
0070: 2A 70 60 93 B6 21 20 00   CB 12 BF 06 BE AA E9 D0  *p`..! .........
0080: 21 FC B6 5B 89 EB D3 7C   E5 AE 29 20 2B C6 47 F5  !..[......) +.G.
0090: FA C5 04 C6 DB A0 76 61   53 C8 AD C5 39 B1 29 06  ......vaS...9.).
00A0: B9 5A 1E 1D 80 5B 26 3E   E0 06 72 43 36 21 F8 4C  .Z...[&>..rC6!.L
00B0: 23 3A C7 A8 47 FE FE D6   4B D5 BC 3A 8B 04 4E 1A  #:..G...K..:..N.
00C0: 86 7F 92 06 46 64 C4 54   C3 A5 36 25 19 C1 78 3E  ....Fd.T..6%..x>
00D0: C7 BD 85 1C 62 E9 87 06   9A A8 83 FC 88 7F 2D 15  ....b.........-.
00E0: 16 C3 13 EF 3B BB 18 11   77 DD C1 34 BB CE FE 74  ....;...w..4...t
00F0: 25 51 25 77 92 7E A2 55   68 D4 B4 98 D4 A5 00 69  %Q%w...Uh......i

]
Root Thread, handling exception: oracle.aurora.vm.ReadOnlyObjectException
Root Thread, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
Root Thread, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
```

Full trace here: http://pastebin.com/bZZyPTBg

When using the same Java code externally from the database from the command line it works fine.

Thanks!
Steve

Comment: Show us some code where the exception is throwed.

Comment: Added code to the main post

Comment: Have you recompiled the Java code?

Comment: Yeah we have, no change - we are about to revoke the permissions and recreate them to see if that helps...

Comment: It didnt help. We are going to trying dropping the Java object and recreating it.

Comment: We've opened an Oracle service request for this, hopefully they can help us...

Comment: @Steve have you resolved this exception please ???

Comment: We changed the Java code and PLSQL to call an external Java app via a script... but I think a DB restart would have fixed it at the end of the day, but the client didnt want the down time!

Comment: unfortunately in our case when this error happens, there is no chance to fix it even after restarting the DB or restarting the OS. it works again only if we reload the classes and after some number of calls, the same error... :(

Comment: how did you changed the Java code and PLSQL to call an external Java app via a script ? possible to send parameters to the java side from plsql ?  thanks!!

Comment: my solution is Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String) ?

Comment: Within our system we a system setup to call a shell script via a DB alert, within that script it then calls the Java code.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4042189/calling-java-from-plsql-causing-oracle-aurora-vm-readonlyobjectexception